# mssql_connect from Symfony's task

Tags: php

I am facing a problem with mssql_connect. I am using symfony1.1. mssql_connect working properly in actions. But I am getting " Call to undefined function mssql_connect()" when i call mssql_connect from symfony task. Any one please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Avinash

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it's a namespace issue.

Try:

```
\mssql_connect(...)
```

Comment: Still I am getting same result " Call to undefined function mssql_connect()"

Comment: $dbh = \mssql_connect("Host", 'username', 'password');
 if (!$dbh || !mssql_select_db('testDB', $dbh)) {
  die('Unable to connect or select database!');
   }

Comment: Hmmm...  Are the two scripts being run in different ways?  Can you check phpinfo() to see if the mssql module is loaded?  Now I'm kind of wondering if one is being run through a web server and one from the command line.  Are two different php.ini files being used?

Comment: No I am using only one ini file.mssql module is already loaded

Comment: It's possible that if you're running it in two different ways, that one way might not be using a php.ini file.  Have you verified that it's loaded?  If it's not a namespace issue, and the function works elsewhere, that leads me to be fairly sure that it's not loaded.

Comment: `php -i` will give you the command line php configuration, the php.ini file used and the list of loaded modules.

Comment: Thanks, In task its loading another ini file from another location. Let me try to change it.

Comment: Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:***.***.***.**** , I am trying to connect remote server.

Comment: $dbh = \mssql_connect("Host", 'username', 'password'); if (!$dbh || !mssql_select_db('testDB', $dbh)) { die('Unable to connect or select database!'); } Now mssql_connect() is working but showing warning "Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:", But same code s working fine in symfony action

Comment: Must be either a different version of the mssql extension (not likely) or a difference in params. Have you double checked them?

Comment: I am getting " PHP Warning:  Module 'mssql' already loaded in Unknown on line 0 " while adding extension=php_dblib.dll in php.ini file

Comment: " Must be either a different version of the mssql extension (not likely) or a difference in params. Have you double checked them? – Corbin 1 hour ago "                                                                  I Have checked everything is same Still I am getting "Warning: mssql_connect(): Unable to connect to server:" same piece of code working throgh symfony actions.

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest method to connect to a SQL server is to route it through a ODBC connection.

1. Administrative Tools -> Data Sources (ODBC)
2. System DNS
3. Add... "SQL Server"

Then just use odbc_connect("sql_test", "user", "pass") instead.